# sql how to set a condition with having count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table

| codice | cfmoglie | cfmarito | data | numero | invitati |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I have to find the couples that are already married.

I'm tryng this one and it works:

```sql
SELECT 'moglie' as persona,
       matrimonio.cfmoglie as cf,
       COUNT(matrimonio.cfmoglie) as già_sposati
FROM   matrimonio 
GROUP BY matrimonio.cfmoglie
HAVING COUNT(matrimonio.cfmoglie)> 1
UNION
SELECT 'marito' as persona,
       matrimonio.cfmarito as cf,
       COUNT(matrimonio.cfmarito) as già_sposati
FROM   matrimonio
GROUP BY matrimonio.cfmarito
HAVING COUNT(matrimonio.cfmarito)> 1;
```

Changing `cfmarito` or `cfmoglie` I have, for example, 7 records, but I need just the couples that have already married, not the person. How I can solve?

Comment: For all foreigners - what do cfmoglie and cfmarito mean? Otherwise at least I can't understand your question at all :(

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table (including any relationships to itself); the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; an explanation of the data and its relationships; and the expected output for that sample data. We cannot answer the question if we do not have and do not understand your table and data.

Comment: cfmoglie is the wife's ssn , cfmarito is the husaband's ssn

Comment: So, let's say Jane was once married to Tom and is now married to John. And John was once married to Mary, then to Rose and is now married to Jane. At last there is some Jill married to some Mike. You'll get: Jane 2 | John 3. (Because you exclude Jill 1 | Mary 1 | Mike 1 | Rose 1 | Tom 1 from the result, as you want their partner count to be greater than 1). What result exactly do you want instead of Jane 2 | John 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions to find the rows where the `cfmoglie` and `cfmarito` have both previously occurred once or more:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT cfmoglie,
         cfmarito,
         data,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cfmoglie ORDER BY data) AS num_moglie,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cfmarito ORDER BY data) AS num_marito
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  num_moglie > 1
AND    num_marito > 1
```

If you want to find couples where at least one partner was already married (rather than both partners) then change `AND` to `OR`.

If you want to find couples who are renewing their marriage vows (i.e. the same couple has already married before) then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT cfmoglie,
         cfmarito,
         data,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cfmoglie, cfmarito ORDER BY data)
           AS num_married
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  num_married > 1
```